# Angular and express server communication issues

Tags: angular, express, mlab

I have to create a simple Angular/Express/mLab combo that lets you create users and verify them.
I created a service in my angular project

```
createTest(email: string, name: string, password: string) {
    this.http.post(this.createUserURL, {
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "password": password
    }).subscribe();
  }
```

And express side:

```
app.post("/create_user",async (req:express.Request,res:express.Response)=>{
    try{
        if(await User.findOne({email:req.body.email})){
            res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already taken!" });
        }else{
            req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10);
            const myUser = new User(req.body)
            await myUser.save()
        }
    }catch (err){
        res.send(err);
    }
})
```

And that works perfectly; I'am able to create a single user. Then I want to verify a registered user, to do that I also created necessary functions:

Angular:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.http.post(this.logInUserURL, {
          "email": email,
          "password": password
        }).subscribe();
      }
```

Express:

```
app.post('/login',async (req:express.Request,res:express.Response) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({email: body.email});
    if(user){
        if(await bcrypt.compare(body.password,user.password)){
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Valid Password" });
        }else{
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid Password" });
        }
    }
})
```

After that i want to be able to recive confirmation on Angular side (for example recive boolean like loginSucces:true) so that i can manipulate with UI.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function that receives and processes the HTTP response data to `.subscribe()` like this:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.http.post(this.logInUserURL, {
          "email": email,
          "password": password
        }).subscribe((data: /* The type of your response */) => { /* YOUR CODE TO DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA */ });
      }
```

But I wonder why you return an error when the passwords match?